# Comparing two dates in SQL in where clause using CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using following query which is working fine for me.

```
   SELECT   SO.OrderNumber, TransactionsLookup.TransactionName, Branches.new_Name AS Branchname, i.new_PostedDate,
                  min(i.new_PostedDate) over(partition by SO.OrderNumber) FirstPostedDate,


          FROM       SalesOrders AS SO INNER JOIN
                     Temp_Invoices i  on SO.SalesOrderId = i.SalesOrderId INNER JOIN
                     Branches ON SO.new_Branch = Branches.new_BranchId INNER JOIN
                     StatusReasonsLookup sl on i.StatusCode = sl.Id
                WHERE
                     SO.new_Transaction =  @AbstractTransactionID 
                     AND SO.new_Branch <> @BranchID_Metro
                   AND ((month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate)) 
                    OR (month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) = year(new_PostedDate)) 
                    OR (month(new_CanceledDate) = month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate)) OR (i.new_CanceledDate IS NULL))
```

Now I have to make date compare cause conditional in where clause using case when something like this;

```
   SELECT   SO.OrderNumber, TransactionsLookup.TransactionName, Branches.new_Name AS Branchname, i.new_PostedDate,
                  min(i.new_PostedDate) over(partition by SO.OrderNumber) FirstPostedDate,


          FROM       SalesOrders AS SO INNER JOIN
                     Temp_Invoices i  on SO.SalesOrderId = i.SalesOrderId INNER JOIN
                     Branches ON SO.new_Branch = Branches.new_BranchId INNER JOIN
                     StatusReasonsLookup sl on i.StatusCode = sl.Id
                WHERE

                  ( CASE When sl.StatusCodeName = 'Canceled'  Then  ((month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate)) 
                                OR (month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) = year(new_PostedDate)) 
                                OR (month(new_CanceledDate) = month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate)) 

                            ) ELSE  (i.new_CanceledDate IS NULL)) END )
                    AND SO.new_Transaction =  @AbstractTransactionID 
                     AND SO.new_Branch <> @BranchID_Metro
```

Can something please guide how can I achieve this. I have tried but still unable to get it done.

Comment: That `CASE WHEN` shouldn't even compile - there's no `boolean` type in SQL Server and nothing compares the value returned by `CASE` with anything. Even if booleans existed, that `CASE` is equivalent to a combination of `AND` and `OR` statements, only far harder to understand

Comment: `AND ((month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate) AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate))` has a code smell to it as well. You should be using proper date logic here or a calendar table.

Comment: The query of CASE WHEN I wrote is simply for explanation of my requirements, it is not a compiled query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something using AND OR

possibly

```
SELECT SO.OrderNumber
    ,TransactionsLookup.TransactionName
    ,Branches.new_Name AS Branchname
    ,i.new_PostedDate
    ,min(i.new_PostedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY SO.OrderNumber) FirstPostedDate
FROM SalesOrders AS SO
INNER JOIN Temp_Invoices i ON SO.SalesOrderId = i.SalesOrderId
INNER JOIN Branches ON SO.new_Branch = Branches.new_BranchId
INNER JOIN StatusReasonsLookup sl ON i.StatusCode = sl.Id
WHERE (
        (sl.StatusCodeName = 'Canceled'
        AND (
            month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate)
            AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate)
            OR month(new_CanceledDate) <> month(new_PostedDate)
            AND year(new_CanceledDate) = year(new_PostedDate)
            OR month(new_CanceledDate) = month(new_PostedDate)
            AND year(new_CanceledDate) <> year(new_PostedDate)
            )
            OR sl.StatusCodeName != 'Canceled'
            AND i.new_CanceledDate IS NULL)
        AND SO.new_Transaction = @AbstractTransactionID
        AND SO.new_Branch <> @BranchID_Metro
        )
```

Comment: Hi, If I add sl.StatusCodeName = 'Canceled', it will apply filter of "Canceled" for whole resultset while I just want to keep it conditional.

Comment: so what is it conditional  on?  You can add that condition to your logic